# Stop a setTimeout function in AngularJS (hint: use $timeout)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, settimeout

I'm making a quiz-type app in which, when user gets a question, a timer of 10 seconds goes like this:

```
$scope.timer2 = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('times up!!!!');
    }, 10000)
}
```

and it is being called when a question arrives like this:

```
timerHandle = setTimeout($scope.timer2());
```

And after this `timer2` execution another question pops up and so on, another way of a question being popped up is that the user selects an option also then a new question comes up. So far so good but the problem is that if suppose 5 seconds were passed and then user selects an option, the "timer2" still shows "times up!!" after 5 more seconds and another timer for the new question also shows "times up!!" if the user hasn't selected any option.

What I'm trying to say is that I want the `timer2` to stop when user selects any option, and then i want again this timer to be called as a new question will arrive.
This is the angular code which executes when user selects an option:-

```
 $scope.checkanswer=function(optionchoosed){
            $http.get('/quiz/checkanswer?optionchoosed='+ optionchoosed).then(function(res){
                if(res.data=="correct"){
                    $scope.flag1=true;
                    $scope.flag2=false;

                }else{
                    $scope.flag2=true;
                    $scope.flag1=false;
                }
                $http.get('/quiz/getquestions').then(function(res){
                console.log("respo");
                $scope.questions=res.data;
                clearTimeout($scope.timerHandle);  //not working
                timerHandle = setTimeout($scope.timer2());
```

Comment: I edited your question because you asked for AngularJS, but your problem is really generical.

Comment: yeah lol thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the service of AngularJS [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout). 
Then do something along these lines:

```
var myTimer = $timeout(function(){
                console.log("hello world")
             }, 5000);

     ....
$timeout.cancel(myTimer);
```

Comment: Much thanks :) I still don't know what was the cause but it worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad it helped:)

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. The [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service is the AngularJS wrapper for `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the MDN documentation for [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

As you can see, that function returns a unique identifier.
At this point, you can call [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) passing that UID as parameter:

```
let myTimeout = setTimeout(myFunction, millis); //Start a timeout for function myFunction with millis delay.
clearTimeout(myTimeout); //Cancel the timeout before the function myFunction is called.
```

Comment: I am using clearTimeout(timerHandle) above but the function doesn't stop. It has been called before but isn't stopping.

Comment: The problem is that you set timerHandle just after the calling of clearTimeout(timerHandle).

Comment: but then again it should stop the first one and then execute the second one, right na?

Comment: Can you take a look at the console and say me for eventual errors? I'm suspicious about the calling to clearTimeout: at first of all timerHandle is never set. It would cause an error.

Comment: Lol there is no error in console the timer is being set and prints up "times up!" after 10 secs.

Comment: Then try changing timerHandle to $scope.timerHandle. I noticed you're getting $scope.timerHandle, but setting timerHandle (in window scope)!

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide working example let me do the best guess.  Your function does not return handle from inner `setTimeout` so it cannot be cancelled. What about such modifications:

```
$scope.timer2 = function() {
    return setTimeout(function() {  // added return statement
        console.log('times up!!!!');
    }, 10000)
}
```

and then

```
timerHandle = $scope.timer2(); // simply call timer2 that returns handle to inner setTimeout
```